# The equivalent definition of compactness

Tags: general-topology

I am studying topology. I know that compact is equivalent to closed and boundes in R^n.

That lead me to two questions.

Under what conditions:
(1)compact is equivalent to closed? 
(2)compact is equivalent to closed and bounded?

What i know is that compact implies closed in Hausdorff space. But the converse doesnt holds. What assumption should be add to make those two statements become true?

Comment: For metric spaces in general, boundedness of a subset is not a property of the topology alone. Because if $d$ is a metric then the bounded metric $e(x,y)=\min (1,d(x,y))$ generates the same topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set is a compact set if and only if whatever net (that is, generalized sequence) you choose made up of elements from the set has a converging subnet with *a* limit belonging to the set.

A set is closed if and only if whatever converging net of elements of the set you choose, all its limits belong to the set. (Thanks to Andreas Blass for correcting me here)

In non-Hausdorff spaces, convergent nets (and sequences) can have more than one limit and the singletons of each of the limits of a given convergent net are not *separated by neighborhoods* and there are no other points whose singleton is not separated-by-neighborhoods from the singletons of the limits, that is given a convergent net each limit and no other point is an accumulation point of *every* set for which one of the other limit is an accumulation point.

That means that if a point belongs to a closed set then all the limits of a net of elements of the set converging to the given point must belong to the set, because all those limits are accumulation points for the closed set.

For a set to be compact instead it is only needed that *some* limit of the subnet belong to the set, so a compact set may not be closed.

All that tries to answer to your point (1). As to the point (2) read next.

Compactness is thought to impose some regularity to the behaviour of nets: a net of point of a compact set may not converge only because it is "made up" of more than one convergent net, so it is possible to extract, for each cluster point of the net, subnets converging to the cluster point.

Nets not converging for other reasons (that can exist only in non-compact sets) have no cluster point at all or are "made up" of convergent nets and nets with no cluster points.

In metric spaces, non-convergent sequences (sequences suffice, instead of nets, to characterize metric topology) can be further decomposed into two categories: non-converging fundamental sequences and non-converging non-fundamental sequences. If a set is complete all fundamental sequences of its elements converge to a point of the set; if a set is totally bounded there are no sequences that are non-fundamental. In finite-dimensional Euclidean spaces equipped with the ordinary topology, those last two things are equivalent to saying: if a set is closed all fundamental sequences of its elements converge to the set; if a set is bounded there are no sequences that are non-fundamental.

In topological linear space, the situation is analogous to that of the metric space, but here we need to revert back to using nets and not simply sequences.

Hope this help.

Comment: The second paragraph, claiming to characterize closed sets, is wrong. It would make all sets closed, because of constant nets. It should rather say that, whenever a net of elements of the set converges, then its limit is also in the set.

Comment: @Andreas Blass thanks for your prompt correction. I'm going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the general definition of compact is that every open cover has a finite subcover.

1) If the space is compact Hasdorff for example, but also in the trivial topology it's true (which normally isn't Hasdorff).

2) Obviously this has to be a metric space (since bounded requires a metric). It's well known that this is true in $\mathbb R^n$, but it's not in general true (for example there are infinit dimensional cases where it fail).

Answer (score 0):

1) In a compact Hausdorff space, any closed subset is compact. Obviously, it is a necessary condition ($X$ is a closed subset of $X$).

2) I don't know what a necessary condition would be, but in a finite dimensional normed vector space over a locally compact metric field $K$, then a closed and bounded set is compact.